# Why is this code throwing an InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, equality, invalidoperationexception

I think that my code should make the `ViewBag.test` property equal to `"No Match"`, but instead it throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

Why is this?

```
string str = "Hello1,Hello,Hello2";
string another = "Hello5";
string retVal = str.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .First(p => p.Equals(another));
if (str == another)
{
   ViewBag.test = "Match";
}
else
{
   ViewBag.test = "No Match"; //this does not happen when it should
}
```

Comment: @SLaks The code returns System.InvalidOperationException instead of diplay "No Match" on the page.

Comment: It doesn't **return** `InvalidOperationException`, it throws it. Mainly because there is no string in that list that is equal to "Hello5". What are you tring to accomplish?

Comment: .First() throws it, if there isn't a match, try FirstOrDefault() and check null

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx), the `First` method throws an `InvalidOperationException` when the sequence on which it is called is empty.  Since no element of the result of the split equals `Hello5`, the result is an empty list.  Using `First` on that list will throw the exception.

Consider using `FirstOrDefault`, instead (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)), which, instead of throwing an exception when the sequence is empty, returns the default value for the type of the enumerable.  In that case, the result of the call will be `null`, and you should check for that in the rest of the code.

It might be cleaner still to use the `Any` Linq method (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx)), which returns a `bool`.

```
string str = "Hello1,Hello,Hello2";
string another = "Hello5";
bool retVal = str.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Any(p => p.Equals(another));
if (retVal)
{
   ViewBag.test = "Match";
}
else
{
   ViewBag.test = "No Match"; //not work
}
```

And now the obligatory one liner using the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
string str = "Hello1,Hello,Hello2";
string another = "Hello5";
ViewBag.test = str.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                   .Any(p => p == another) ? "Match" : "No Match";
```

Note that I also used `==` here to compare strings, which is considered more idiomatic in C#.

Comment: I **would** upvote this, but the code's unclear I have absolutely no idea what (s)he's trying to do.

Comment: I interpreted the question such that that he or she is trying to set `ViewBag.test` to "Match" when the variable `str` contains the variable `another` in between commas, and "No Match" otherwise.  Is that what you meant, @user2398766?

Comment: I agree with that, but I can't tell!

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
bool hasMatch = str.Split(',').Any(x => x.Equals(another));

ViewBag.test = hasMatch ? "Match" : "No Match";
```