# Unable to validate the return value from web api 2.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I am creating a C# web API 2.0. along with a Test project. The API works fine. When I run the test project and hover over the `contentResult`, which is the value returned from the API, it has the correct value. However, all the Assert statements fail. In the code below I am returning an object, `DeliveryCode`. Even when I return string, I get the same error.

The controller:

```
public class CodeGeneratorController : ApiController
{
    ICheckCodeExist _checkCodeExist;
    IGenerateBrandNewCode _generateBrandNewCode;
    IGenerateFromExistingCode _generateFromExistingCode;
    IDeliveryCode _deliveryCode;

    public CodeGeneratorController(ICheckCodeExist checkCodeExist, IGenerateBrandNewCode generateBrandNewCode, IGenerateFromExistingCode generateFromExistingCode, IDeliveryCode deliveryCode)
    {
        _checkCodeExist = checkCodeExist;
        _generateBrandNewCode = generateBrandNewCode;
        _generateFromExistingCode = generateFromExistingCode;
        _deliveryCode = deliveryCode;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/CodeGenerator/{percentage}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int percentage)
    {
        if (_checkCodeExist.IsCodeAvailable(percentage))
        {
            _deliveryCode.Code = _generateFromExistingCode.GetDeliveryCode();                   
            return Ok(_deliveryCode);
        }
        else
        {
            _deliveryCode.Code = _generateBrandNewCode.GetDeliveryCode();
            return Ok(_deliveryCode);
        }            
    }
}
```

Concrete class 1:

```
public class GenerateFromExistingCode : IGenerateFromExistingCode
{
    public string GetDeliveryCode()
    {
        return "XYZ456";
    }
}
```

Concrete class 2:

```
public class GenerateBrandNewCode : IGenerateBrandNewCode
{
    public string GetDeliveryCode()
    {
        return "ABC123";
    }
}
```

Test

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDeliveryCodeWithPercentage()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<ICheckCodeExist> checkCodeExist = new Mock<ICheckCodeExist>();
    checkCodeExist.Setup(x => x.IsCodeAvailable(50)).Returns(true);             
    var generateBrandNewCode = new GenerateBrandNewCode();
    var generateFromExistingCode = new GenerateFromExistingCode();
    var deliveryCode = new DeliveryCodeValue();

    var codeGeneratorController = new 
    CodeGeneratorController(checkCodeExist.Object, generateBrandNewCode, 
    generateFromExistingCode, deliveryCode);

    //Act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = codeGeneratorController.Get(50);            
    var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<DeliveryCodeValue>;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
    Assert.AreEqual("XYC456", contentResult.Content.Code);
}
```

Errors:

> ContentNegotiator -
>   '((System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult)actionResult).ContentNegotiator'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>           Formatters: '((System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult)actionResult).Formatters'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>           Request: '((System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult)actionResult).Request'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this code throwing an InvalidOperationException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636374/why-is-this-code-throwing-an-invalidoperationexception)

Comment: Before boxing 'actionResult' to 'OkNegotiatedContentResult', debug and check what the true type of 'actionResult' is.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting to the wrong type in the test.

In the system under test you return

```
return Ok(_deliveryCode);
```

where `_deliveryCode` is

```
IDeliveryCode _deliveryCode;
```

thus the return type would be

```
OkNegotiatedContentResult<IDeliveryCode> //Interface
```

In the test you try to cast it to

```
OkNegotiatedContentResult<DeliveryCodeValue> //Concrete implementation
```

which would result in

```
var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<DeliveryCodeValue>;
```

being *null*

Change the code to

```
var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IDeliveryCode>;
```

and it should behave as expected.

Finally, `GenerateFromExistingCode.GetDeliveryCode` returns `"XYZ456"`, but the assertion is checking for `"XYC456"`

```
Assert.AreEqual("XYC456", contentResult.Content.Code);
```

Verify that that is indeed the desired assertion.

Comment: Hi NKosi, I have changed the code to var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IDeliveryCodeValue>; still contentResult comes as null. It should be "XYZ456". I have fixed it.

Comment: @Massey I misread the code, and copied the wrong interface. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Hi NKosi, I have changed my controller code to, return Created("", _couponCode); and the test code to var contentResult = actionResult as CreatedNegotiatedContentResult<ICouponCode>; Now it's working fine